# I'm unable install the android plug in Eclipse helio in windows

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin

When i'm trying to install android plugin in eclipse i got this error

" An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Unable to read repository at http://downloads.myeclipseide.com/downloads/products/eworkbench/helios/9.0M1/plugins/org.maven.ide.eclipse.maven_embedder_0.10.0.me201003101716.jar.
Read timed out  "

please any one can give me a solution

Answer (score 0):

go to eclipse preference, network connection. select manual not native